# Make textarea border shadowy

Tags: html, css, textbox, textarea

I have both `textarea` and `input` in my form. The border of `input` is shadowy, while the border of `textarea` is solid. If I put in `border: none;` for `textarea`, then there's no border at all. I want them to be the same. Can I do it?

Comment: Please add snapshots of what you want.

Comment: Are these default borders you are talking about? You can set your borders explicitly and thus style them as you wish.

Comment: @ralph.m Yes, these are default borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "shadowy" borders, you might be better off getting rid of the borders altogether and using box-shadow instead. Here's a simple example:

```
input, textarea {
border: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```